# Array serialize issue in smarty tpl

Tags: php, serialization, smarty

I want save the output of an array in a hidden div in smarty tpl. I used `{$product|@print_r}` to do that. But I want that array to be serialized. Is there any way to get serialized `$product` array. Pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried {$product|@serialize}?

Comment: Thanks but. I have already tried it. and it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

best practice for serializing:

```
//serialize
$string = base64_encode(serialize($array));

//unserialize
$array = unserialize(base64_decode($string));
```